# Laravel 5.7 Comment count for different posts

Tags: php, laravel

I am stucked at point where i got comment count for posts but it shows count of all comments of all posts on every post. I would like to know how to output in blade comment count for post ID

here is controller:

```
  $posts = $posts->orderBy("posted_at", "desc")
        ->paginate(config("blogetc.per_page", 10));

    $comments = BlogEtcComment::all();


    return view("blogetc::index", [
        'posts' => $posts,
        'title' => $title,
        'comments' => $comments,
    ]);
```

blade:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
<section class="blog_area p_120">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="blog_left_sidebar">
                        <article class="blog_style1">
                            <div class="blog_img">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="blog_images/{{$post->image_large}}" alt="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="blog_text">
                                <div class="blog_text_inner">
                                    <div class="cat">
                                        <a class="cat_btn" href="{{$post->url()}}">{{$post->slug}}</a>
                                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{$post->created_at}}</a>
                                        <a href="{{$post->url()}}"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{count($comments)}}</a>
                                    </div>
                                    <a href="{{$post->url()}}"><h4>{{$post->title}}</h4></a>
                                    <p>{!! $post->generate_introduction(400) !!}</p>
                                    <a class="blog_btn" href="{{$post->url()}}">Lasīt vairāk</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You need to use `groupBy` clause.

Comment: I found another way but dont know is this is good practice. I changed in my blade -"{{count($comments)}}" to "{{count($post->comments)}}" and it works for me

Comment: changing blade won't help since you still do `{{count($comments)}}` and `$comments = BlogEtcComment::all();` will always contain all records of all posts. Can you show the models ?

Answer (score 1):

//Quickfix:

//assuming your posts table is called posts and that in your blogetccomments table //you have a post_id column pointing to the original post. Try something like

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->leftJoin('blogetccomments', 'posts.id', '=', 'blogetccomments.post_id')
    ->selectRaw('posts.*, count(blogetccomments.post_id) as commentcount')
    ->groupBy('posts.id')
    ->get();
```

In your blade template, Access the comments count for each post, as follows..

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
...
{{$post->title}}...
{{$post->commentcount}}

...
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) to get count of comments for a specific post :

```
$posts = $posts->withCount('comments')
        ->orderBy("posted_at", "desc")
        ->paginate(config("blogetc.per_page", 10));
```

Above would require you to have `comments` relation on your `Post` Model :

`Post` Model :

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BlogEtcComment::class);
}
```

`BlogEtcComment` Model :

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

And then in blade :

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <p>Post : $post->id</p>
  <p>Comments : $post->comments_count</p>
@endforeach
```